# Connect Windows server 2003, php 5.2.6 to Win Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, server, php-mssql

I have a production support site that runs on Windows Server 2003, SQL Server 2008 r2, php 5.2.6 and I have to connect it to a new server with windows server 2019 with SQL Server 2019.

When I try to connect from the old server to the new one, the `mssql_connect()` function gives me an error. I think it's the fault of wrong drivers, but I'm afraid that the versions take too many years.

Is there any solution?
Is there a driver that is compatible with server 2003 that allows you to connect to SQL Server 2019?

Comment: Yes I have searched for drivers, but those that are compatible with Windows 2003, I understand are too obsolete for sql server 2019.
So I seemed to understand from some guidelines on the microsoft website

Comment: I'm able to connect to SQL Server 2017 with PHP 5.2.10 and `mssql_connect()`, but I can't test the connection with SQL Server 2019. What is the error?

Comment: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 192.168.1.4,1433 in C:\...          which driver version are you using?

Comment: Library version 7.0, php-mssql.dll (5.2.10.10) and ntwdblib.dll (8.00.194).

Comment: sorry for the question, for library version 7 what do you mean? ntwdblib and php_mssql (5.2.6.6) are ok.

Comment: From `<?echo phpinfo()?>`, section `mssql`. Only a note, but I'm not able to connect to `Microsoft Azure`.

Comment: PHP Driver for SQL Server does not [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-operating-systems) Windows Server 2003. So, using ODBC is probably the first option.

Comment: I had already tried through odbc but without success. Now I am trying to move the site to the new server to have more elasticity with the drivers